# Does performance suffer for using module-level Private variables and subs instead of passing variables using functions in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, module, scope

Which of the following is better for performance?

- to use module-level Private variables and subs for subroutines
- to explicitly pass the variables to functions and to assign
  variables explicitly to the caller using the defined functions: OutputVariables = MyLittleProcedure(InputVariables).

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to worry about performance? Otherwise I would suggest you invest energy in more important aspects of your code -- readability, easier to debug, correctness.

Comment: This is not a performance question but an issue of code robustness - unless you have a specific reason *not* to directly pass values as arguments to other methods, then you should not be using global variables for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is really a one size fits all answer to this question of performance, other than its probably not worth the risk. General programming good practice says stick to local variables to avoid accidental changes to global variables (especially if the variable is being used in multiple functions, and more so when used in callbacks or events). VBA is single threaded as far as I know, so at least you don't have to worry about simultaneous access to the global variables (mutexes and semaphores... *scratches head*). Functions with local variables is also easier to debug, future proof and reuse in other programs.

Now in theory, if you are calling a rather small/short function with lots of large local variables often, the overhead associated with variable initialisation (which VBA does, but e.g. C doesn't) could potentially give a performance advantage to global variables. If you are passing several arguments, these have to be copied/duplicated from the calling memory to the function stack (overhead again). Passing large arrays as function arguments in any case passes as a pointer (ByRef), and data actually resides in global memory space.

For the counter-example, exceedingly large amounts of global variables remains in memory all the time, making your program memory hungry (compared to local variable memory that gets recycled between function calls), and slows your system down overall. Also, local arguments and variables sit on the stack, possibly even in processor registers, so memory access should be faster (Probably less of an issue these days in 64 bit address space, but I'm guessing - its been a while since I had third year comp science and I'm not really sure how windows handles memory segmentation, paging, virtualisation, protection etc. these days).

Last point, if you start to worry about the performance overhead of memory management, you probably shouldn't be coding in VBA anyway. I remember seeing inline assembler code in turbo pascal coded graphical functions, where every instruction was carefully considered for performance. They used local variables and functions with arguments if I recall :)